# Objective-C: multiple if and return statements with least amount of code

Tags: objective-c

This is a question on how to code this efficiently with as little as code possible. It already works but I need to incoporate the paramenter `numberOfShapes`. That if 1 returns ■, if 2 ■■, if 3 ■■■ etc...

I could do some extra if statemets and extra return statements. If Square->if number = 1> return ■, if number >2 return ■■ etc.. But that is a whole lot of code for something very simple.

What is the best way of coding this with the least amount of code?

```
- (NSString *)getShape: (NSNumber *)shape numberOfShapes: (NSNumber *)number
{
    if ([shape isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:SQUARE]]) return @"■";
    if ([shape isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CIRCLE]]) return @"●";
    if ([shape isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TRIANGLE]]) return @"▲";

    return @"?";
}
```

Comment: Never go for least amount of code, rather go for best efficient code.

Comment: @AKV Not always true. Refactoring is important for readability, and premature optimization is evil.

Comment: @Radu: You are correct but number of lines will increase for extra break;... I dont know what is OP's goal.

Comment: @AKV A switch statement wouldn't need `break` statements, just `return` statements.

Comment: I am learning Objective-C and trying to pick up good habits! switch case is indeed a good option

Comment: Minor nitpick: In Objective-C/Cocoa, a method prefixed with "get" typically returns something by reference. See for example [`-[NSIndexSet getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexSet/getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:)

Comment: As a general rule I don't like to return from inside a method.  But as a general rule, I don't like general rules.

Comment: @HotLicks, you have great general rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)getShape: (NSNumber *)shape numberOfShapes: (NSNumber *)number
{
    unsigned shapeInt = [shape unsignedIntValue];
    if (shapeInt >= 3)
        return @"?";
    NSString *shapeStr = [@"■●▲" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(shapeInt, 1)];

    // Add autorelease here, if using MRR...
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    unsigned numberInt = [number unsignedIntValue];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberInt; i++)
        [result appendString:shapeStr];
    return result;
}
```

I don't see the point of using `NSNumber` objects to pass parameters like this, as they can't do anything that a simple `NSUInteger` or `unsigned` can, and are more expensive to use.

Comment: I prefer your solution! as it is all confined to one method! Which I prefer for methods that is sparse in code.

Comment: @TomLilletveit Please note that my code assumes `SQUARE == 0`, `CIRCLE == 1` and `TRIANGLE == 2`!

Answer (score 6):

Largely a question of taste unless you have some really heavy performance requirements.

One way to do it could be to set up a dictionary with the map from numbers to glyphs.

Assuming that you have a static variable `glyphs`, initialize it in the class' `initialize` method:

```
static NSDictionary *glyphs;

+ (void)initialize 
{
    glyphs = @{
      @(SQUARE):@"■",
      @(CIRCLE):@"●",
      @(TRIANGLE):@"▲"
    };
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
- (NSString *)shapeForNumber:(NSInteger)shape 
{
    NSString *glyph = [glyphs objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: shape]];

    return glyph ? glyph : @"?";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a *demonstrated* performance problem with the code?  Otherwise, I think a switch is pretty clear.  Or, fewer lines and O(1) is ...

```
// declare this earlier
static NSArray *shapeChars = @[ @"■", @"●" /* etc. */ ];

// then
return [shapeChars objectAtIndex:[shape intValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Enter the concept of loops. Also, why do you use `NSNumber`s for this? Plain old `int`s are good enough.

```
- (NSString *)getShape:(int)shape numberOfShapes:(int)number
{
    if (shape == SQUARE]) return [self shapeRepeated:@"■" nTimes:number];
    if (shape == CIRCLE]]) return [self shapeRepeated:@"●" nTimes:number];
    if (shape == TRIANGLE]]) return [self shapeRepeated:@"▲" nTimes:number];

    return @"?";
}

- (NSString *)shapeRepeated:(NSString *)shape nTimes:(int)n
{
    return [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:n withString:shape startingAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: @GavinMiller That's why I've chosen this :)

Comment: nice code, i like. The NSNumber are used cause the values is passed around a lot used in Arrays etc...

Comment: @TomLilletveit In that case, you can still pass down `[number intValue]` to this method.

Comment: H2CO3: yeah! the question is only where I choose to do this, The method that calls this method is very dense, so i figured it would be easier just to pass the object to this method and do the conversion in this method, so the code in the calling method don´t get even more dense.

Comment: @TomLilletveit No, in general methods should do what their task is, and not do the homework for other methods.

Comment: But you are porpably right! I should maybe intimidate after getting the NSNumbers out of the array convert it back to a int

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)getShape: (NSNumber *)shape numberOfShapes: (NSNumber *)number
{
    switch([number intValue]): {
        case SQUARE: return @"■";
        case CIRCLE: return @"●";
        case TRIANGLE: return @"▲";
        default: return @"?";
    }
}
```

To incorporate "number":

```
- (NSString *)getShape: (NSNumber *)shape numberOfShapes: (NSNumber *)number
{
    NSString* result = nil;
    switch([number intValue]): {
        case SQUARE: result = @"■"; break;
        case CIRCLE: result = @"●"; break;
        case TRIANGLE: result= @"▲"; break;
        default: result = @"?";
    }
    NSString* realResult = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
       realResult = [realResult stringByAppendingString:result];
    }
    return realResult;
}
```

You could neaten it up by using a char value for result, but I'm too lazy.